# 那透明的心 - transparent heart?

Tags: mandarin

What is a transparent heart in the context of the chorus lines of the song 致你 by 苡慧?

Transparent in the sense of being visually transparent or some other sensory perception?

The chorus lines are:

```
若想念是凋谢的云
乘着风也飘向你
降落在你耳边低语
像沉默的打字机
满怀热烈情绪
写不出 会别离 太爱你
到最后
我只好小心翼翼
尝试着偷偷靠近
触碰你那透明的心
猜你启封的表情
只敢写下开篇的
致你
```

Comment: Well, @De Rien did a good job answering the other parts of the song back in Mar 27, 2022, perhaps he / she would like to complete the favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, "transparent heart" means "a heart that can be easily seen through", which implies "純潔" - pure; honest; innocent; simple of a person's thinking, character, etc..